# how many times will the for loop execute?

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 1; i % 2 != 0; i = i+2){
// do something
}
```

The answer is supposed to be infinite, but if the loop is supposed to stop until i%2 does not equal zero, won't it stop at the first iteration (1%2 = 1)?

*sorry, i was supposed to equal one but I understand now thank you!

Comment: No, it will not stop until the condition *is false*. It will always loop because an odd number is not evenly divisible by 2.

Comment: **NOW** it will iterate approximately 4,503,599,627,370,495 times - because `9007199254740991 + 2 = 9007199254740992` (due to limitations of floating point arithmetic)

Comment: This would take 300 years to reach - so "infinite" is an apt description :p Though, during those 300 years there would be some speed improvements in computing, so perhaps you wont have to wait that long

Answer (score 0):

No, because the condition states if the loop executes or not. Not if it stops. As the initial value is 1 and 1 % 2 == 1 and 1 != 0 is true, so the loop is executed. Then as the increment is 2 it will only allow odd numbers which never have a % 2 of 0.

This proves it conclusively:

```js
for (var i = 1; i % 2 != 0; i = i + 2) {
    console.log('--iteraction start--');
    console.log('i => ' + i);
    console.log('i % 2 => ' + (i % 2));
    console.log('i % 2 != 0 => ' + (1 % 2 != 0));
    if (i > 10) break; // this is here so we don't have to wait eternally
    console.log('--iteraction end--');
}     
console.log('and so on...');
```

Comment: Yeah, I realised you had the original code :p this code though will stop - see my comment in the question :p